# Using wildcards in Jira JQL

Tags: jira-agile

In the question [Query JIRA versions using wildcards with JQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795108/query-jira-versions-using-wildcards-with-jql)
The answer is to use something like `project=MYPROJ and fixversion in versionMatch("DEVX*")`    using the asterix at DEVX*.

In my case I have: getting all the issues from CBS-6840 up to CBS-6849
**project = CBS AND key in ("CBS-684*")**
Similar to the question above what would a need to add instead of *versionMatch*

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the many add-ons in the Atlassian Marketplace to see if anyone has scripted functions to provide the sort of functionality you are looking for.  A pretty accessible work-around that I would suggest is below (using the [JIRA / Hipchat issues themselves](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/HCPUB-739?filter=-5&jql=project%20%3D%20HCPUB%20and%20issuekey%20%3E%3D%20%22HCPUB-730%22%20AND%20issuekey%20%3C%3D%20%22HCPUB-739%22) as an example).  It uses the strict ordered-ness of JIRA keys without needing a wildcard.

```
project = HCPUB and issuekey >= "HCPUB-730" and issuekey <= "HCPUB-739"
```

You can also always generate the list yourself, which can be a little tedious:

```
project = HCPUB and issuekey in ('HCPUB-730','HCPUB-731',...)
```